# Failed open av input:-825242872 Server returned 401 Unauthorized (authorization failed) after I modify the route table

Tags: ffmpeg, routing, camera

I debug a board with two net cable connect with a web camera with a Switch. When one net cable is broken, I want the board can use another cable to connect the web camera use rtsp protocol. Because these devices in the same local lan , so i modify the route table to let another cable can connect the camera. But I find after i modify the route table , bind the camera to another cable ,the when i try to connect the camera, i get the `Failed open av input:-825242872  Server returned 401 Unauthorized (authorization failed)`  .
why would this happen?

Comment: When you say you modify the routing table, what exactly do you do? What are the IP addresses of all network interfaces (camera, board 1 & 2)? Is there perhaps some simple firewall on the camera?

Comment: You should [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1728157/edit) your post with the IP addresses of the concerned device and the routing table from before and after the change.

Comment: Oh, the camera ip is ``192.168.100.64``; the board has two eth, these ip are :``eth0:192.168.100.110`` and ``eth1:192.168.100.111``. When the begining , I use route command bind ``192.168.100.64`` to eth0,in my program when find the cable is broken with eth0, i will delete route item with ``192.168.100.64`` and then bind ``192.168.100.64`` to eth1.